# Waiting for a file to be downloaded using async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm creating a game using Firebase cloud storage for user data. If the user does not have a local file the cloud storage should download a save file from their user profile (determined by a unique id). The issue is that this code stops Unity from running and will cause it to get stuck during the Application.onbeginplay phase. (Load is called on awake). Part of the issue here is mostly my lack of experience working with async.

```
private async Task TryDownloadData(string filepath)
{
    //find location of the users save file
    _storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
    _dbUrl = _storage.GetReferenceFromUrl(URL);
    _saveFileLocation = _dbUrl.Child(ID + "/test.sav");

    //Wait for the file to be downloaded (or failed). If failed a blank save is used
    await _saveFileLocation.GetFileAsync(filepath);

    return;
}

public async void Load(string filepath)
{
    //If local file does not exist... then try to download from cloud storage
    if (!File.Exists(GetPathFromSaveFile("moneyStackSave")))
    {
        await TryDownloadData(GetPathFromSaveFile(filepath));
    }

    //Load the objects from the file that exists or not
    LoadObjects(LoadFile(filepath));
}
```

Not shown in the code block above is the insides of the LoadObjects method which if a local file is not found then it will start the user from a fresh save (catches the event that no local or cloud data exists).

Comment: Can you elaborate a little, especially for those of us unfamiliar with Unity? Is `Load` getting called by Unity directly because it implements a particular interface? Typically you would want `async` methods to return a `Task` which then gets awaited, but that can get tricky if you're stuck with a `void` event handler. And phrases like "stops Unity from running and will cause it to get stuck" can be a little ambiguous.